# Unable to write to a pipe in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe, popen

I have a third party utility that I have to call from my application to initialize some of their stuff. I've chosen to call it by using `popen` because I need to write a password to stdin.

I's a simple use case:

```
...
FILE *f = popen("utility-bin", "w");
fwrite(myPassword.c_str(), 1, myPassword.size(), f);
fflush(f);
pclose(f);
...
```

However, no matter how I try, the stream is never sent, and the utility remains blocked waiting for the password.

If I call the utility from a regular Linux shell, on the other hand, I can just type the password and everything works.

So my question is: Is it possible for an application to block data from coming from pipes, but still accepting from a normal user shell? And, if that's the case, is there anything I can do to make it accept my pipe input?

PS: When I call the utility from the shell, many signals are beeing handled. `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+z`, for example, do nothing.

Comment: Can you do a `strace` on the process (run it normally from the terminal) and post how it tries to read the login, and from where ?

Comment: Among others, sftp does this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for an application to block data from coming from
>   pipes, but still accepting from a normal user shell

It can call [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) which will tell it if input comes from a terminal or not.

> if that's the case, is there anything I can do to make it accept my
>   pipe input

There is a way, but you might not like it:

1. Open a pseudoterminal using `posix_openpt` `grantpt` and `unlockpt`. You now have the
   "master" fd
2. Fork a new process
3. Call `setsid()` in the new process to kill its terminal association
4. In the child call `ptsname` on the fd obtained in step 1
5. Open the name obtained from `ptsname` and call `TIOCSTTY` on it - it becomes the controlling terminal
6. Duplicate the descriptor obtained in step 5 into `STDIN_FILENO`
7. Exec your program

You can probably adapt [the function `ptyFork`](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/pty_fork.c.html) from TLPI for this or [the function `pty_fork` from APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/code3e.html).

At this point you can write into the master fd - as if it were a pipe - from your process and the child will think it comes from a terminal.

Comment: By using your answer, I was able to find a very good explanation about  the whole process [here](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html). I made minor adjustments in the example that uses `fork` and `execvp` and worked like a charm =).